# Noda Time: Period.Between returning incorrect value

Tags: c#, .net, date, period, nodatime

I have a trouble with NodaTime lib. My goal: compute Year/Month/Date between two dates. So, here is my test example:

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>>
        {
            new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(new DateTime(1980, 1, 1), new DateTime(1983, 12, 31)),
            new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(new DateTime(2009, 1, 1), new DateTime(2015, 01, 23))
        };
        var totalPeriod = Period.Zero;
        foreach (var tuple in list)
        {
            var dateFrom = tuple.Item1;
            var dateTo = tuple.Item2;
            var ld1 = new LocalDate(dateFrom.Year, dateFrom.Month, dateFrom.Day);
            var ld2 = new LocalDate(dateTo.Year, dateTo.Month, dateTo.Day);
            var period = Period.Between(ld1, ld2, PeriodUnits.YearMonthDay);
            totalPeriod += period;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Years: {0}, Months: {1}, Days: {2}", 
            totalPeriod.Years, 
            totalPeriod.Months,
            totalPeriod.Days);
        Console.Read();
    }
```

The output is:
**Years: 9, Months: 11, Days: 52**

It's wrong for me. I want to get, for example, the next output (Of course, the output depends on number of days in month, assuming that there are 31 days in our month):
**Years: 10, Months: 0, Days: 21**

So, I want that days was rounded to years and month. How I can get this?

**The answer:**
Using Matt's answer I created the next solution:

```
 foreach (var tuple in list)
        {
            var dateFrom = tuple.Item1;
            var dateTo = tuple.Item2;
            var period = Period.Between(LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dateFrom).Date, LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dateTo).Date, PeriodUnits.YearMonthDay);
            totalPeriod += period;
        }
        // trying clarify the period
        while(totalPeriod.Days >= 30)
        {
            totalPeriod = totalPeriod - Period.FromDays(30);
            totalPeriod = totalPeriod + Period.FromMonths(1);
            while (totalPeriod.Months >= 12)
            {
                totalPeriod = totalPeriod - Period.FromMonths(12);
                totalPeriod = totalPeriod + Period.FromYears(1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm sure @jonskeet will jump on this.  But how would `Period` roundup 52 days to 1 month and 21 days?  Each month has a different number of day!s!!

Comment: I don't think your "next solution" is a particularly good one, to be honest. If you only want the difference between *two* dates, why not just use `Period.Between` once? Normalizing periods with months and years just doesn't sound like a good idea to me. Heck, if you add up every period between January 1st and January 2nd, then January 2nd and January 3rd etc until December 31st and January 1st, you *won't* end up with a year. What is the bigger picture here? What are you really trying to achieve? You may well want to just collect the number of days (which you can do with PeriodUnits).

Comment: I going to explain what I want to get. 
I should get duration of employment of a citizen should be presented in Years, Months and Days.
Example: Mike Smith is programmer. He started to work since 1 Jan 1980 at Microsoft. He left from Microsoft in 31 Dec 1983.
After that he does not work anywhere until 1 Jan 2009. Since 1 Jan 2009 he have started to work on Google. He left from Google in 23 Jan 2015.
So, there are two periods in total: 
1st = 1 Jan 1980 - 31 Dec 1983
2nd = 1 Jan 2009 - 23 Jan 2015
In result I should get: Years: 10, Months: 0, Days: 21 
But I got: Years: 9, Months: 11, Days: 52

Comment: This result is not correct for my purposes. I know that my "next solution" is smell. But I don't know how to get the exact one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Richard was right in his comment on the OP.  The problem is that the months and years aren't distinct quantities unto themselves.  One must have a frame of reference to "count" them.  You have that reference when you do the `Period.Between` operation, but it's lost by the time you try to add the periods together.

If you check the periods that are being added, it makes sense:

```
First:  Years: 3, Months: 11, Days: 30
Second: Years: 6, Months: 0,  Days: 22
Total:  Years: 9, Months: 11, Days: 52
```

In order to round as you would like, the 22 days being added to the 30 days would somehow have to know which month was being referenced.  Even if you retained the original information - which one would you use?  You could well have a 28-day month on one side, and a 31-day month on the other.

The best you could do would be to artificially round the results yourself afterwards, and choose a flat value (such as 30 days) to represent all months.

Oh, one minor thing (unrelated to your question) - To go from a `DateTime` to a `LocalDate`, try `LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dt).Date`.  :)

Comment: Thank you, Matt! I am supposing that option when I wrote that question, but I think there is an exact solution. I will post my resulting code in the question. P.S. And great thank you for LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dt).Date way :) It is really helpful!